# Choosing Clustering Method based on results

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, recommendation-engine, k-means, dbscan

I'm using WEKA for my thesis and have over 1000 lines of data. The database includes demographical information (Age, Location, status etc.) followed by name of products (valued 1 or 0). The end results is a recommender system.
I used two methods of clustering, `K-Means` and `DBScan`.

When using `K-means` I tried 3 different number of cluster, while using `DBscan` I chose 3 different epsilons (Epsilon 3 = 48 clusters with ignored 17% of data, Epsilone 2.5 = 19 clusters while cluster 0 holds 229 items with ignored 6%.) Meaning i have 6 different clustering results for same data.

How do I choose what's best suits my data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is "best"?

As some smart people noticed:

> the validity of a clustering is often in the eye of the beholder

There is no objectively "better" for clustering, or you are not doing cluster analysis.

Even when a result actually is "better" on some *mathematical* measure such as separation, silhouette or even when using a supervised evaluation using labels - its still only better at optimizing towards some mathematical goal, *not to your use case*.

K-means finds a local optimal sum-of-squares assignment for a given k. (And if you increase k, there exists a better assignment!) DBSCAN (it's actually correctly spelled all uppercase) always finds the optimal density-connected components for the given MinPts/Epsilon combination. Yet, both just optimize with respect to some mathematical criterion. **Unless this critertion aligns with your requirements, it is worthless**. So there is no best, until you know what you need. But if you know what you need, you would not need to do cluster analysis.

### So what to do?

Try different algorithms and different parameters and **analyze the output with your domain knowledge, if they help you with the problem you are trying to solve**. If they help you solving your problem, then they are good. If they do not help, try again.

Over time, you will collect some experience. For example, if the sum-of-squares is meaningless for your domain, don't use k-means. If your data does not have meaningful density, don't use density based clustering such as DBSCAN. It's not that these algorithms fail. They just don't solve *your* problem, they solve a *different* problem that you are not interested in. And they might be really good at solving this other problem...